# Can $M^k$ have an eigenvalue which is not the $k$-th power of an eigenvalue of $M$ in a finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field and, for an $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
let $M \in \mathbb{F}^{m \times m}$ be a matrix. Furthermore, let
$\mathbb{E}$ be the splitting field of the characteristic polynomial of $M$. Thus,
$M$ has $m$ eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m \in \mathbb{E}$.

One may show that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $j \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$, $\lambda_j^k$ is an eigenvalue of $M^k$. However, since there might be some distinct $i$ and $j \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$ such that $\lambda_i^k = \lambda_j^k$ for a $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $$\Lambda_k\triangleq\{\lambda_1^k, \ldots, \lambda_m^k\}$$ might not contain all $m$ eigenvalues of $M^k$.

**Question:** Is it possible for $M^k$ to have an eigenvalue in $\mathbb{E}\setminus \Lambda_k$?

Comment: I work over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$. Here, the char.pol. $\chi_M(t)$ decomposes into linear factors. Now the question is, what is the char.pol. of $M^k$? Well, I would try the following: $$\chi_{M^k}(t) = \det(M^k - t \cdot 1_{n \times n}) = \det(\prod^{k-1}_{i=0}(M - \sqrt[k]{t} \zeta^{i}_k \cdot 1_{n \times n})) = \prod^{k-1}_{i=0}\det(M - \sqrt[k]{t} \zeta^{i}_k \cdot 1_{n \times n}).$$
Does this help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very reasonable question, as I think there is no super-elementary way to see that $M^k$ might not acquire some "exotic" eigenvalues.

In fact, over any field, Jordan canonical form is decisive: it shows that the only possible eigenvalues of the $n$th power are $n$th powers of the original eigenvalues. (Yes, some may become the same...)